# python unsurpported operand datatypes for float and int

Tags: python, linear-regression

hey i am trying to do linear regression using gradient descent and i have been facing this error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'int'
```

the code is below

```
b = 0
a = 0
L = 0.0001
epochs = 10000
n = len(X)
n = 1
epsilon = 0.0001  # Stop algorithm when absolute difference between 2 consecutive x-values is less than epsilon
diff = 1
while diff > epsilon & n < epochs:  # 2 stopping criteria is set
    Y_pred = b*X + a
    cost = (1/n)*sum([val**2 for val in (Y-Y_pred)])
    D_b = (-2/n) * sum(X*(Y - Y_pred))
    D_a = (-2/n) * sum(Y - Y_pred)
    b = b - L*D_b
    a = a - L*D_a
    diff = abs(Y_pred -Y)
    j = j + 1
    y = Y_pred
    print('x')

print('The value of b is {},cost is {} and the value of a is {} when itstheminimum'.format(b,cost,a))
```

error is in this line

```
while diff > epsilon & n < epochs:  # 2 stopping criteria is set
```

any suggestions or alternative would be appreciated

Comment: `&` is bitwise AND. Use `&&` for logical AND.

Comment: Alternatively, this code works is you put brackets around like `while (diff > epsilon) & (n < epochs):`

Comment: @Barmar you mean `and`

Answer (score 1):

It returns the error because you use `&` to represent `and` logical operator. In Python, you should use `and` as shown below:

```
while diff > epsilon and n < epochs:
```